# How to overload operator + with the parameters of a class?

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, operator-overloading

I am learning about overloading operators in c++ and I have done this code aboout the sum of two imaginary numbers, formed by the real part and the imaginary part.

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 

class Complex { 
private: 
    int real, imag; 
public: 
    Complex(int r, int i) {
        real = r; 
        imag = i;
    } 


    Complex operator + (Complex const &num1, Complex const &num2) { 
        Complex res; 
        res.real = num1.real + num2.real; 
        res.imag = num1.imag + num2.imag; 
        return res; 
    } 

    void print() { 
        cout << real << " + i" << imag << endl; 
    } 
}; 

int main() 
{ 
    Complex c1(10, 5), c2(2, 4); 
    Complex c3 = c1 + c2;
    c3.print(); 
}
```

Something should be wrong because it shows a lot of errors, notes and warnings :(

```
error: ‘Complex Complex::operator+(const Complex&, const Complex&)’ must take either zero or one argument

error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘Complex’ and ‘Complex’)

note:   ‘Complex’ is not derived from ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’
```

Comment: Ok, what errors, notes and warnings?

Comment: You have overloaded them like friend functions.

Comment: You have a double `num1.imag` in `res.imag = num1.imag + num1.imag;`

Comment: Note: C++ already has [std::complex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have defined `operator+` is fine, expect that it needs to be a `friend` function. Also, note that `Complex res;` will not compile because you don't have a default constructor.

You could define the function like this:

```
friend Complex operator + (Complex const &num1, Complex const &num2) { 
   return {num1.real + num2.real, num1.imag + num2.imag};     
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fMp1OJ).

Note also, that I fixed the bug where you are adding the imaginary part of `num1` twice.

Comment: Thanks for advising that ````num1```` was written twice because I hadn't noticed. :)

Answer (score 5):

A *binary* (2 parameter) operator can't be a class member, it needs to be a standalone function instead:

```
class Complex {
...
public:
    ...
    friend Complex operator + (Complex const &lhs, Complex const &rhs);
    ...
};

Complex operator + (Complex const &lhs, Complex const &rhs) {
    return Complex(
        lhs.real + rhs.real,
        lhs.imag + rhs.imag
    );
}
```

Which can also be inlined:

```
class Complex {
...
public:
    ...
    friend Complex operator + (Complex const &lhs, Complex const &rhs) {
        return Complex(
            lhs.real + rhs.real,
            lhs.imag + rhs.imag
        );
    }
    ...
};
```

So, a statement like `c1 + c2` gets processed as `operator+(c1, c2)`.

A *unary* (1 parameter) operator, on the other hand, must be a class member that acts on `this` as the left-side value:

```
class Complex {
...
public:
    ...
    Complex operator + (Complex const &rhs) const {
        return Complex(
            real + rhs.real,
            imag + rhs.imag
        );
    }
    ...
};
```

Then a statement like `c1 + c2` gets processed as `c1.operator+(c2)`.